# C# Split Container

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make it to resize to fit the form, example when I try to maximize the form, the split remains at the same dimensions, and I want it to have the new size of the form. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything to solve your problem?

Comment: You need to write some code that runs on the onresize handler.

Comment: Please expand your question with what you've already tried, and some code extracts maybe.

Comment: Set `Anchor` to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right`

Comment: I don't know why you encountered this issue because dragging-n-dropping a `SplitContainer` onto a form by default makes it filled and resize accordingly to the form size. If not, you can set `Dock` Property to `DockStyle.Fill` and it should work.

Comment: EDIT: Sory, I didn't read the header :) /EDIT He doesn't speak about SplitContainer but about using splitter probably.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate and store proportion of both sides of the split and to store it in a field. 
You have to set panelLeftProp on panel resizing.
You have to check panel minimum width if it's necessary.

```
    double panelLeftProp;

    private void panelLeft_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panelLeftProp = panelLeft.Width / this.Width;
    }

    private void Form_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            return;

        panelLeft.Width = (int) (this.Width * panelLeftProp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I added an event to the resize event of the panel (which gets called on form resize) and then set that container's width and it worked fine.

```
   private void splitContainer1_Panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        this.splitContainer1.Width = this.Width / 10;        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use set Dock Property to DockStyle.Fill

for example..

```
           splitContainer1.DockStyle= Dock.Fill
```